# Dynamically set the OPTIONS for Select on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, select, prototypejs

I am setting almost 10+ Select control using data got from Ajax call; Following is my Code:

```
function arrayToOptionList(list) {

    var optList = [];
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        optList.push("<option value ='" + list[i][1] + "' >" + list[i][0] + "</option>");
    }

    return optList.join("");

}

 opt = arrayToOptionList(list);
 $("select_ctrl_id").update(opt);
```

I know that IE has significant issues for dom manipulation. And after couple of googling I have optimized my code for IE. I am still getting that my IE becomes Not responding for a while when setting the Select controls.
Can you guys please suggest what else I can do to improve the issue ?

I am using prototype.js for setting the select control and I am facing the issue on IE 8/9

Comment: From the IE profiling I am seeing that the update is taking most of the time. Any idea if it'll improve if I use jQuery instead ? Or I need to take care of anything else that I missed ?

Comment: Where are `opt` and `i` declared?

Comment: maybe you should try a webworker or promise http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/tracks/developing-html5-apps-jump-start follow course no 5.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using `innerHTML` for this works best for IE, so try using that in combination with plain DOM-scripting:

```
document.querySelector('#select_ctrl_id').innerHTML = opt.join('');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rKc9Q/)

Comment: Is it working on IE ?! innerHTML for Select has known issues on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built in methods provided by Prototype - for instance

```
var select = $("select_ctrl_id").clone();
list.each(function(i){
    select.insert(new Element('option',{'value':i[1]}).update(i[0]));
});
$("select_ctrl_id").replace(select);
```

this creates a copy of the select DOM element and inserts all the options in the select and then replaces the select.

Comment: can you add a snippet of the html you are applying this to to your question above. As well as a few of the values from the ajax call so we can test it out

Comment: From my ajax call the list is being returned which looks pretty much like : [['option name 1','option value 1'],['option name 2','option value 2']]

Answer (score -3):

try the old fashion way http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

```
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option=document.createElement("option");
option.text="Kiwi";
try
  {
  // for IE earlier than version 8
  x.add(option,x.options[null]);
  }
catch (e)
  {
  x.add(option,null);
  }
```

Comment: Do you really think adding each element at a time will improve the performance ?!!

Comment: maybe i should test it on IE